# Openlayers3 leaflet osm problem of displaying data

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2

I'm a newbie in GIS world and recently built my own [private osm tile server infrastructure](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) that will be used in closed environment only and it works as a charm.

I tested the server inserting Leaflet code

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.1333,11.5667], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mytileserver/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([48.1333,11.5667]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

The marker  exactly points  to Munich and it works perfectly.

Next I tried to do almost the same by using Openlayers example:

```
var centerpos = [48.1333,11.5667]; // position in degrees
var newpos = ol.proj.transform(centerpos,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:900913');
var map = new ol.Map({
    view : new ol.View({
        projection : 'EPSG:900913', 
        center : newpos,
        zoom : 8.5,
        minZoom : 2,
        maxZoom : 12.5
    }),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
               source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
         ],
   target : 'map'
});
```

and the map created shows somewhere near Djibouti - Africa.

What have I done wrong with Openlayers3 example ?

Or  did I do something wrong with installation of mapnik/postgis/osm ?

Answer (score 3):

Try switching your lat/long positions. Leaflet and Openlayers have different approaches there...

leaflet uses lat-lon: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng
openlayers uses lon-lat: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope your answer will help other students.